# Scrolls to a React component when a button is clicked on another component

Tags: reactjs, scroll

This all in a single page. When I press the `Button` in `NavBar`, I want the screen to scroll to `SubscriptionForm` component. I have tried using `useRef` and `forwardRef` while following [this tutorial](https://robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/scroll-a-react-component-into-view/) but it doesn't seem to work in my case. I have also tried  [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)'s `<Link />` and it works with essentially two lines of code. But, what I want to know is how to make it possible without the use of react-scroll.

My folder and code structure is as follows -

```
src
|-- Home
|   |-- Home.js
|   |-- SubscriptionForm
|   |   |-- SubscriptionForm.js
|-- NavBar
|   |-- NavBar.js
|-- App.js
```

In `SubscriptionForm.js` -

```
const SubscriptionForm = () => {
  return (
    <Form>...</Form>
  )
}
```

In `Home.js` -

```
import SubscriptionForm from './SubscriptionForm/SubscriptionForm'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      // other components
      <SubscriptionForm />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In `NavBar.js` -

```
const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      // other stuff
      <Button />
    </div>
  )
}
```

In `App.js` -

```
import NavBar from './NavBar/NavBar'
import Home from './Home/Home'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar />
      <Home />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using `useRef` and `fowrawdRef`.
You will need to create a ref inside `App` component and forward it all the way through, to the `form` element using `forwardRef`.
Then pass the ref as a prop and use it in the `NavBar` component.
Working example: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-starter-forked-8mty5?file=/src/index.js)